# How to pass the object values with in the products object here to smarty from php through json

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, json, smarty

POST http://www.chirubhai.com/modules/trackmyorder/ViewOrderStatus.php

```
200 OK
        145ms   
491dc0a...f293.js (line 2)
HeadersPostResponseHTMLJSONCookies
```

JSON:

```
{
   "id_address_delivery":"3819",
   "id_address_invoice":"3819",
   "id_shop_group":"1",
   "id_shop":"1",
   "id_cart":"11708",
   "id_currency":"1",
   "id_lang":"1",
   "id_customer":"1994",
   "id_carrier":"23",
   "current_state":"19",
   "secure_key":"57fd1d90574aa441e059c10b8714d6bb",
   "payment":"Cash on delivery (COD)",
   "module":"cashondelivery",
   "conversion_rate":"1.000000",
   "recyclable":"0",
   "gift":"0",
   "gift_message":"",
   "mobile_theme":"0",
   "shipping_number":"",
   "total_discounts":"962.50",
   "total_discounts_tax_incl":"962.50",
   "total_discounts_tax_excl":"962.50",
   "total_paid":"8662.50",
   "total_paid_tax_incl":"8662.50",
   "total_paid_tax_excl":"8662.50",
   "total_paid_real":"0.00",
   "total_products":"9625.00",
   "total_products_wt":"9625.00",
   "total_shipping":"0.00",
   "total_shipping_tax_incl":"0.00",
   "total_shipping_tax_excl":"0.00",
   "carrier_tax_rate":"0.000",
   "total_wrapping":"0.00",
   "total_wrapping_tax_incl":"0.00",
   "total_wrapping_tax_excl":"0.00",
   "invoice_number":"0",
   "delivery_number":"0",
   "invoice_date":"0000-00-00 00:00:00",
   "delivery_date":"0000-00-00 00:00:00",
   "valid":"0",
   "date_add":"2014-12-19 15:44:23",
   "date_upd":"2014-12-19 15:44:39",
   "reference":"APYAKKKZF",
   "id":"5440",
   "id_shop_list":null,
   "id_order_state":19,
   "invoice":false,
   "order_history":false,
   "carrier":{
      "id_reference":"23",
      "name":"Ecom Express",
      "url":"",
      "delay":"Standard Delivery Time",
      "active":"1",
      "deleted":"0",
      "shipping_handling":"0",
      "range_behavior":"0",
      "is_module":"0",
      "is_free":"1",
      "shipping_method":"1",
      "shipping_external":"0",
      "external_module_name":"",
      "need_range":"0",
      "position":"7",
      "max_width":"0",
      "max_height":"0",
      "max_depth":"0",
      "max_weight":"0.000000",
      "grade":"5",
      "id":23,
      "id_shop_list":null,
      "id_tax_rules_group":"0"
   },
   "address_invoice":{
      "id_customer":"1994",
      "id_manufacturer":"0",
      "id_supplier":"0",
      "id_warehouse":"0",
      "id_country":"110",
      "id_state":"332",
      "country":"India",
      "alias":"gitanjali",
      "company":"jowelsouk",
      "lastname":"Rout",
      "firstname":"Chiranjibi",
      "address1":"cutack odisha",
      "address2":"",
      "postcode":"753001",
      "city":"cuttack",
      "other":"",
      "phone":"",
      "phone_mobile":"9933003456",
      "vat_number":"",
      "dni":"",
      "date_add":"2014-08-28 15:27:45",
      "date_upd":"2015-01-30 11:05:43",
      "deleted":"1",
      "id":3819,
      "id_shop_list":null
   },
   "address_delivery":{
      "id_customer":"1994",
      "id_manufacturer":"0",
      "id_supplier":"0",
      "id_warehouse":"0",
      "id_country":"110",
      "id_state":"332",
      "country":"India",
      "alias":"gitanjali",
      "company":"jowelsouk",
      "lastname":"Rout",
      "firstname":"Chiranjibi",
      "address1":"cutack odisha",
      "address2":"",
      "postcode":"753001",
      "city":"cuttack",
      "other":"",
      "phone":"",
      "phone_mobile":"9933003456",
      "vat_number":"",
      "dni":"",
      "date_add":"2014-08-28 15:27:45",
      "date_upd":"2015-01-30 11:05:43",
      "deleted":"1",
      "id":3819,
      "id_shop_list":null
   },
   "inv_adr_fields":[
      "firstname lastname",
      "company",
      "vat_number",
      "address1",
      "address2",
      "postcode city",
      "State:name",
      "Country:name",
      "phone_mobile"
   ],
   "dlv_adr_fields":[
      "firstname lastname",
      "company",
      "vat_number",
      "address1",
      "address2",
      "postcode city",
      "State:name",
      "Country:name",
      "phone_mobile"
   ],
   "invoiceAddressFormatedValues":{
      "firstname":"Chiranjibi",
      "lastname":"Rout",
      "company":"jowelsouk",
      "vat_number":"",
      "address1":"cutack odisha",
      "address2":"",
      "postcode":"753001",
      "city":"cuttack",
      "State:name":"Orissa",
      "Country:name":"India",
      "phone_mobile":"9933003456"
   },
   "deliveryAddressFormatedValues":{
      "firstname":"Chiranjibi",
      "lastname":"Rout",
      "company":"jowelsouk",
      "vat_number":"",
      "address1":"cutack odisha",
      "address2":"",
      "postcode":"753001",
      "city":"cuttack",
      "State:name":"Orissa",
      "Country:name":"India",
      "phone_mobile":"9933003456"
   },
   "currency":{
      "id":1,
      "name":"Indian Rupee",
      "iso_code":"INR",
      "iso_code_num":"356",
      "sign":"Rs",
      "blank":"1",
      "conversion_rate":"1.000000",
      "deleted":"0",
      "format":"1",
      "decimals":"0",
      "active":"1",
      "prefix":"Rs ",
      "suffix":"",
      "id_shop_list":null
   },
   "discounts":[
      {
         "id_order_cart_rule":"1447",
         "id_order":"5440",
         "id_cart_rule":"4547",
         "id_order_invoice":"0",
         "name":"EXTRA10",
         "value":"962.50",
         "value_tax_excl":"962.50",
         "free_shipping":"0"
      }
   ],
   "invoiceState":{
      "id_country":"110",
      "id_zone":"3",
      "iso_code":"OR",
      "name":"Orissa",
      "active":"1",
      "id":332,
      "id_shop_list":null
   },
   "deliveryState":{
      "id_country":"110",
      "id_zone":"3",
      "iso_code":"OR",
      "name":"Orissa",
      "active":"1",
      "id":332,
      "id_shop_list":null
   },
   "products":{
      "6953":{
         "id_order_detail":"6953",
         "id_order":"5440",
         "id_order_invoice":"0",
         "id_warehouse":"0",
         "id_shop":"1",
         "product_id":"77",
         "product_attribute_id":"0",
         "product_name":"Rotary Men's Wrist Watch GS0010104",
         "product_quantity":"1",
         "product_quantity_in_stock":"1",
         "product_quantity_refunded":"0",
         "product_quantity_return":"0",
         "product_quantity_reinjected":"0",
         "product_price":9625,
         "reduction_percent":"30.00",
         "reduction_amount":"0.000000",
         "reduction_amount_tax_incl":"0.000000",
         "reduction_amount_tax_excl":"0.000000",
         "group_reduction":"0.00",
         "product_quantity_discount":"9626.000000",
         "product_ean13":"",
         "product_upc":"",
         "product_reference":"GS0010104",
         "product_supplier_reference":"",
         "product_weight":"0.000000",
         "tax_computation_method":"0",
         "tax_name":"",
         "tax_rate":0,
         "ecotax":"0.000000",
         "ecotax_tax_rate":"0.000",
         "discount_quantity_applied":"0",
         "download_hash":"",
         "download_nb":"0",
         "download_deadline":"0000-00-00 00:00:00",
         "total_price_tax_incl":"9625.000000",
         "total_price_tax_excl":"9625.000000",
         "unit_price_tax_incl":"9625.000000",
         "unit_price_tax_excl":"9625.000000",
         "total_shipping_price_tax_incl":"0.000000",
         "total_shipping_price_tax_excl":"0.000000",
         "purchase_supplier_price":"13750.000000",
         "original_product_price":"13750.000000",
         "id_category_default":"11",
         "prod_barcode":"",
         "id_product":"77",
         "id_supplier":"0",
         "id_manufacturer":"13",
         "id_shop_default":"1",
         "id_tax_rules_group":"0",
         "on_sale":"0",
         "online_only":"0",
         "ean13":"",
         "upc":"",
         "quantity":"0",
         "minimal_quantity":"1",
         "price":"13750.000000",
         "wholesale_price":"13750.000000",
         "unity":"",
         "unit_price_ratio":"0.000000",
         "additional_shipping_cost":"0.00",
         "reference":"GS0010104",
         "supplier_reference":"",
         "location":"",
         "width":"0.000000",
         "height":"0.000000",
         "depth":"0.000000",
         "weight":"0.000000",
         "out_of_stock":"2",
         "quantity_discount":"0",
         "customizable":"0",
         "uploadable_files":"0",
         "text_fields":"0",
         "active":"1",
         "redirect_type":"",
         "id_product_redirected":"0",
         "available_for_order":"1",
         "available_date":"2014-06-07",
         "condition":"new",
         "show_price":"1",
         "indexed":"1",
         "visibility":"both",
         "cache_is_pack":"0",
         "cache_has_attachments":"0",
         "is_virtual":"0",
         "cache_default_attribute":"0",
         "date_add":"0000-00-00 00:00:00",
         "date_upd":"2014-08-21 12:39:02",
         "advanced_stock_management":"0",
         "threesixty_status":"0",
         "image":{
            "id":3950,
            "id_image":"3950",
            "id_product":"77",
            "position":"1",
            "cover":"1",
            "legend":{
               "1":""
            },
            "image_format":"jpg",
            "source_index":"\/var\/www\/html\/LiveCodeBase\/img\/p\/index.php",
            "id_shop_list":null
         },
         "image_size":null,
         "current_stock":87,
         "tax_calculator":{
            "taxes":[

            ],
            "computation_method":1
         },
         "product_price_wt":9625,
         "product_price_wt_but_ecotax":9625,
         "total_wt":"9625.000000",
         "total_price":"9625.000000",
         "customizedDatas":null,
         "customizationQuantityTotal":0,
         "id_address_delivery":"3819"
      }
   },
   "customizedDatas":false,
   "total_old":7700,
   "hook_orderdetaildisplayed":""
}
```

Comment: i passed the value to my smarty like for "id_order_state" i used            $('#id').html(jsonData.id_order_state) in my javascript file
But for the "product_name" will any body suggest how to pass the value.

Comment: i used like this to transfer value through javascript to template file...

                    success: function(jsonData) {
                    if (jsonData) {
                    $('.order-detail-id').html(jsonData.reference);
                            $('.order-updated-date').html(jsonData.date_upd);
                            $('.order-detail-carrier').html(jsonData.carrier.name);
                    }}

Answer (score 0):

Steps to do this:
You can use ajax to achieve this:
First Encode the data into JSON object
Then decode the data and fetch it in the form of a key value pair. 
Please refer to JSON tutorials in W3schools website.
Hope it helps.

Comment: i encoded this from php file using ajax and got this response but how i ll pass the values of 'products' object to my smarty file using json in my javascript file...

Comment: loop through the items which you got from that object. Please refer to this link :http://www.w3schools.com/json/json_http.asp

Comment: i passed the value to my smarty like for "id_order_state" i used $('#id').html(jsonData.id_order_state) in my javascript file But for the "product_name" will any body suggest how to pass the value.

Comment: i used like this to transfer value through javascript to template file... success: function(jsonData) { if (jsonData) { $('.order-detail-id').html(jsonData.reference); $('.order-updated-date').html(jsonData.date_upd); $('.order-detail-carrier').html(jsonData.carrier.name); }}